# How to get specific user's data when open a card view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I search a user based on the name or email and click on that card view. I want the screen to display the user's data from firebase.
How do I get that user's Id based on that? I used a bundle but I am getting an error.

Here is my code for the individual page.

```
public class UserSingleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnsendFriendRequest;
    private TextView displayName,displayEmail,displayId;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_single);

        //.....

        //Here is the error
        String userId=getIntent().getExtras().getString("userId");//look for the user Id

        mUserDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String display_name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String display_email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                displayName.setText(display_name);
                displayEmail.setText(display_email);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the viewHolder.

```
public class FriendsViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private DatabaseReference userDB;
    public TextView name,email,userId;

    public FriendsViewHolders(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(), UserSingleActivity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Here is the error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.myapplication.UserSingleActivity.onCreate(UserSingleActivity.java:29)
```

Comment: How do you add the `userId` to the `Intent`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a value that hasn't been previously saved in the bundle. 
Before starting the activity, you should use something like:

```
intent.putExtra("userId", name.getText().toString());
```

Or instead of name.getText().toString(), you should put the name you will load from the other class.
This would save the value and you should be able to access it later.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this properly but my userId is not the name. I did try to put `intent.putExtra("userId", userId.getText().toString());` but since I didn't want the screen to display userId therefore I didn't create the textView for userId, I get an error at `userId.getText()`

Comment: You're trying to access an object called "userId", however, you aren't adding anything called "userId" to the intent before starting the activity. If you use `intent.putExtra("userId", "This is the id")`, you would load "This is the id" instead of getting an error

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. `intent.putExtra("userId", "This is the id")`Do I add this line of code in my viewHolder class or my userSingleActivity? Do I still need the `String userId=getIntent().getExtras().getString("userId");`? Also, thank you for your help!

Comment: In the viewHolder, between `Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(), UserSingleActivity.class);` and `v.getContext().startActivity(intent);`.
You would still need `String userId=getIntent().getExtras().getString("userId");`

Comment: I did that but then i get the error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference` for the line `String display_name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
`

Comment: That would be a problem related to your Firebase. Your program is trying to load a value that can't be found there. Are you saving the name and userId to the firebase at any moment?

Comment: My data structure is users-random-key(userId)with childs name and email.

Answer (score 0):

```
mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String display_name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String display_email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                displayName.setText(display_name);
                displayEmail.setText(display_email);
            }
```

from above code when you're doing

```
String display_name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String display_email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
```

send this to other classAdapter where you're putting to show.

Comment: Thanks for helping. How do I send this to the adapter? Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: Send data to parameterized constructor... New MyAdapterClass(name,age,jobtitle);